# Foreign Key Coming from 2 Primary Keys from Distinct Tables

Tags: sql

I have a doubt about how to establish a relationship *one-to-many* between 2 tables when the table from the ***"many"*** side has a foreign key field that receives data from 2 primary keys from distinct tables.

the problem is that it is not possible to establish a relationship *one-to-many* between **tblInput** (one) and **tblFabricatedProductComponents** (many) tables. the same happens between **tblFabricatedInput** (one) and **tblFabricatedProductComponents** (many) tables.

please, have a look in the attached schema. I think you guys will understand much better. this field is *highlighted in red*.

thanks in advance.

p.s.: my idea is that I'd have to split **tblFabricatedProductComponents** into:

**tblFabProdComponentsFromInput**

and

**tblFabProdComponentsFromFabricatedInput**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I unterstand you correctly, you have two types of inputs: simple ingredients like sugar, coconut, etc, and fabricated inputs like coconut cream, which consists of multiple simple ingredients. If so, I would combine the `tblInputs` and `tblFabricatedInputs` and introduce a new field `input_type` like this:

[image]

Important: `tblFabrInputIngred` hasn't any relation with `tblFabrProdComp`. It is just a detail table to `tblInputs`. `tblFabrProdComp` has relation only to `tblInputs` and `tblFabrProducts`.

And if you want to calculate, how many sugar you need for a coconut cream cake, then you can do that with a simple join.

Comment: hi @derstauner. your solution shown works like a charm once that I'll not need to split tblFabricatedProductComponents into 2 tables, otherwise I'd have to put 2 subforms on the **Fabricated Products** screen. on the **tblInputs** table I created an **input_type** field so I can filter by type on the **id_input** (only fabricated inputs) and **id_ingred** (all but fabricated inputs), both from **tblFabrInputIngred**. about the fabricated input price (on the tblInputs table), it will star with 0,00 value but will be able to be updated right after registering its ingredientes by update query.